# How to modify just the first list in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

While solving a problem, I've come across this phenomenon and found the result kind of weird somehow.

Problem: Given a list D containing many lists, such as

`D = [[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]` (6 rows, 6 columns).

I want to change the first list of D into `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]` so the resulting D is supposed to be

`D = [[0,1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]`

But when I used this expression `D[0][0] = 1` (because I'd like to do a for loop through `D[0]` and change every element of `D[0]`), the list D will be

`D = [[1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0]]`

Question: I don't know what was happening there, can anyone explain to me what's happend?

Comment: Please update your question with your real code that generates `D`.

Comment: All your `list`s in `D` refer to the same `list`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: My code to generate D is D = [[0]*6]*6

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
D[0] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
```

output

```
>>> D = [[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
>>> D[0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> D[0] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
>>> D
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

Comment: I've figured out the essence of the problem. Your way's helpful. Thanks a lot!!!